# Solving non-linear first order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, substitution

I have the following differential equation problem but I couldn't proceed any further -

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{\frac{-a~y}{x}}{1- ~b~\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^n\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)^m}$$

where, $x \in [0,1] ~\text{and} ~ y \in [0,1]$

But I can't solve it down.

I have tried $y= uy_1 ~~~
\text{where}, ~ y_1 = x^{\frac{n}{m}}~$, but it didn't help.

Wolfram gives the solution as -
$$y(x) = c_1 \exp( \int  \frac{a}{x - b \frac{x^{m - n + 1}}{(-x + 1)^m}} \, dx) $$

How to simplify the integral?

I just wanted a hint that whether it can be solved? If yes, please just tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Where does this equation come from? Using a bit of Wolfram magic, try turning it into an exact equation or separating variables.

Comment: @Tyma This equation is my own problem. I tried wolfram but it failed to provide any solution.

Comment: I am highly doubtful this has a closed form.

Comment: @K.defaoite It can't be solved?

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash I did try wolfram again. It was getting an error back then. It gave the answer. Can you please look at this? Really be helpful. Please.

Comment: Interesting comment upvotes. I tried an n=m=3 case and it got some less general function times a hypergeometric function.

Comment: Thank you again @Tyma Gaidash for putting in so much efforts. I am also trying to make some assumption to make solution more intuitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{\frac{-a~y}{x}}{1- ~b~\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^n\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)^m}$$
Consider $x'$ instead of $y'$. Then this is Bernoulli's differential equation:
$$-ay\frac{dx}{dy}= {x- ~b~x^{1-n}\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)^m}$$

Comment: Thanks! I am new to differential equation and still learning. I want to find value of y expressed as x. If I do this and then manipulate to express y in terms of x, this won't change the expression, right?

Comment: You're welcome. You can check the wiki page on Bernouilli first DE. I guess you're right...But its not always sure you will find a closed form with elementary functions. @ElinaGilbert

Comment: Thanks for this! Can you please also look at the solution I posted in the question? Is the integration solvable? I posted it as a separate question here - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4240646/indefinite-Integration-of-power-function-in-division-form where I tried to solve it but couldn't. Isn't it solvable?

Comment: sure will y take a look at it...Looks like the integral is not  that easy. @ElinaGilbert  Did you read Jacquelin's answer ?  Looks like this differential equation has no closed form with elementary functions.

Comment: Ohh yes! I was just asking you again to assure that I didn't miss anything. Thanks for all your answers. They are helpful.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{\frac{-a~y}{x}}{1- ~b~\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^n\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)^m}$$

$$\frac{dx}{dy}= -\frac{x}{a~y}+\frac{b}{a} \frac{y^{m-1}}{(1-y)^m} x^{1-n}$$

$$x^{n-1}\frac{dx}{dy}= -\frac{x^n}{a~y}+\frac{b}{a} \frac{y^{m-1}}{(1-y)^m}$$
Let $X=x^n$
$$\frac{1}{n}\frac{dX}{dy}= -\frac{X}{a~y}+\frac{b}{a} \frac{y^{m-1}}{(1-y)^m}$$
This is a first order lineaer ODE. Solving it involves an integral which closed form is an hypergeometric function.

$$X(y)=C\:y^{-n/a}+\frac{b~n}{a~m+n}\:y^m\:{_2F_1}(m\:,\:m+\frac{n}{a}\:;\:m+\frac{n}{a}+1\:;\:y)$$
$C$ is an arbitrary constant.

$_2F_1$ denotes the Gauss hypergeometric function.
$$x(y)=\left(C\:y^{-n/a}+\frac{b~n}{a~m+n}\:y^m\:{_2F_1}(m\:,\:m+\frac{n}{a}\:;\:m+\frac{n}{a}+1\:;\:y) \right)^{1/n}$$

$y(x)$ is the inverse function of the above.

Comment: Thanks! What will be the inverse function for hypergeometric function? Won't an inverse of this will give me the solution close to the form I posted in my question. Can you please tell if the integral I posted can be solved? I posted another question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4240646/indefinite-integration-of-power-function-in-division-form where I solved it further but couldn't solve the integral. Isn't it solvable?

Comment: Do you know what is a "closed form" ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression . No closed form doesn't mean that there is no solution. This means that the solution cannot be expressed with a finite number of standard functions. This is very usual in real life. Then one uses numerical calculus or series approximates.

Comment: This is a more insightful answer as it has the implicit form of the function. Anyways, try finding the inverse via [**inversion theorem**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/InversionFormulas.html) to come up with a (complicated) series solution. Also the convergence of the inversion series may be problematic.

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash Thanks for the clue!